# How to override JSON field from read-only base class and use child field instead?

Tags: java, json

I have a base class (read-only) to fetch data from external API:

```
public class Manager {
 // so many fields
 public User user;
 // ...
}
```

Since field user is lost some fields, so I need to create new User class.

```
public class NewUser extends com.readonly.User {

    public String avatarUrl;
    public String fullname;
    public String address;
    // ....
}
```

Then I create **NewManager** and use it to fetch data from API.

```
public class NewManager extends com.readonly.Manager {
 // so many fields
 public NewUser user;
 // ...
}
```

But I got Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sovannarith.model.NewManager declares multiple JSON fields named user
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:931) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
```

**Note**

- API have field named : *user*
- In both **Manager.class** and **NewManager.class** has field named **user**
- I want to use field name *user* of **NewUser.class**, not of **User.class**

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Use super.user to access the User.class variable, still your exception won't go away because there are 2 candidates for the same key user, you will have to change the variable name.

Comment: @user12047085 yes, so how to override it ? I mean how to use same field ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no stringent requirements to use GSON, then try to use Jackson(ObjectMapper), it can serialize objects with same field names. (Jackson pretty much better IMHO)